# Change Page Content via jQuery after Uploading File - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I don't know if something like this has already been asked and answered, but since no matter what search query I make, nothing seems to be close to what I am looking to do. I am working on a project where the user will upload a file. Once the file has been uploaded it will show the user a success message as well as some file info. I am trying to keep this all within one page, if possible, but can't seem to get it to work. File gets uploaded, but the info does not show.

Here is something like what I am working with:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['uploadFile']) && isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "files/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $message = "\"" . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "\" uploaded successfully...";
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload File</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".uploaded-file-info").hide();

            $(".uploadForm").submit(function() {
                $(".upload-form").hide();
                $(".uploaded-file-info").show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="upload-form">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="uploadForm" >
            <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="uploadFile" value="Upload File" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="uploaded-file-info">
        <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Like I said, the file gets uploaded, but the form doesn't hide and the file info (`$message`) doesn't show. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you're getting mixed up between server-side and client-side code. When you submit the form, the page will be refreshed. If you don't want the form to show again, don't echo it to the browser in your PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the JQuery part :

```
$(".uploadForm").submit(function() {
            $(".upload-form").show();
            $(".uploaded-file-info").show();
        });
```

coupled with this line :

```
<form method="post"
```

The JQuery part is saying : As soon as the form on the page is submitted, Show the information DIV.

The "Form" part just say : Submit the form.

So, when you click the button, the form is submitted and at the same time, the JQuery is executed. But then the form that you just posted needs to "refresh" the page to get the response back from the server. Basically, the JQuery you wrote display your div while you submit it. Meaning that it will work for a fraction of a second but will display an empty div because the response of the server is not there yet.

What you probably want to do is something like :

1. When the page loads
2. And there is content in the uploaded-file-info
3. Show the info and hide the form.

Add a Style tag with the following :

```
<style>
.uploaded-file-info {
        display: none;
}
</style>
```

It will always hide the uploaded-file-info when the page loads.

Then, change your JavaScript code with :

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($('.uploaded-file-info > p').html() != "") {
          $(".uploaded-file-info").show();      
      }
    });
</script>
```

It says that when the page loads, if something is present inside the children

of the element "uploaded-file-info", then show it. Otherwise, do nothing.

---

An easier solution would be to display the block, with php (so on the server side), only if a file was uploaded. No need for JQuery (client side) code.

Remove all the JQuery code and code within "<style>" tags and replace surround your "div class="uploaded-file-info" with an IF like this :

```
<?php if ($message != '') { ?>
    <div class="uploaded-file-info">
    <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Here's what will happen then:

- you post (from your browser) the form
- the server receives your post
- if there is a file uploaded, it will initiate your "message" variable
- and if the message variable exists, the server will put the "div uploaded-file-info" into the response. If not, everything surrounded by the "if" won't be put into the response.
- your browser will receive the response and display it on screen.

Comment: Technically `'.uploaded-file-info > p'` will never be empty because of the PHP within it.

Comment: Another way to see if it will really be empty is to check the source of the page. Go to your page and type "ctrl+u" (will work on most browsers) or find where the "view source" option is. You'll see what I mean. You won't see <?php ... ?> in any pages.  For example, if you check the sources of this page on stack overflow, do you see any part of the server code (php, asp.net, whatever it is)? No, because it was already executed by the server. If you do see such server code in your web page source, it's because there is a problem with the server and it didn't executed the code.

Comment: I have to apologize. I was trying to pass off `$message` without making sure it was set. So, it was outputting an error. This makes no longer makes it empty. After I added `if(isset($message)) { ... }` it worked. Thank you! Marked your solution as the answer. I would +1 it as well, but my "reputation" isn't high enough for that. Once again, thanks!